# Datareader not working with Select Upper and Group By Upper

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqldatareader

I am trying to get data from a Microsoft SQL database using c# in visual Studios 2015 Express. All of the commands I have used so far work. Now I am trying to execute this command with SqlDataReader:

```
SELECT UPPER(Company) FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY UPPER(Company) HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

Here is my code:

```
//open the sql connection
sqlConn.Open();

/*
    * This Sql command will get the field entries from all the selected fields and group them into selection groups.
    * 
    * This is important because it gives a list of arguments to group docId's with.
    */

string selectCommand = "SELECT UPPER(Company) FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY UPPER(Company) HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;";

// Declare list for storing select groups. This will be returned
List <String> groupList = new List<string>();

// Set up table reader
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, sqlConn);
dataRead = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

for (int i = 0; i < dataRead.FieldCount; i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine("DATAREAD: '" + dataRead.GetName(i) + "' .");
}

while (dataRead.Read())
{
    // select string for selecting groups
    string select = "";
    foreach (string colname in staple.fieldsToList())
    {
        // check for null
        if(dataRead[colname] == DBNull.Value)
        {
            select = select + "NULL,";
        }else{
            select = select + dataRead[colname].ToString()
        }

    }
    //store the select string in a list
    groupList.Add(select);
}

return groupList;
```

When this code gets to the dataRead[colname] part, it throws an error saying :

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Company
```

So I checked the names in dataRead and found that the index where Company should have been had an empty string. I replaced the UPPER(Company) in my selectCommand string with Company and it works fine, so somehow using the UPPER() command is making the DataReader initialize without the proper names.

Anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT UPPER(Company) As Company FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY UPPER(Company) HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

If you apply an sql function like `UPPER` without applying alias it returns `(No column name)` for the result.

Comment: Works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the name back in:

```
SELECT UPPER(Company) AS Company ...
```